# Streaming over a Java list to populating a Map

Tags: java, java-stream

Java 11 here. I have the following POJO:

```java
@Data // Lombok; adds getters, setters, all-args constructor and equals and hashCode
public class Fliflam {
    private String merf;
    private String tarf;
    private Boolean isFlerf;
}
```

I have a method that validates a `Flimflam` and returns a `List<String>` of any errors encountered while validating the `Flimflam`. I can change this to return `Optional<List<String>>` if anyone thinks thats helpful for some reason, especially when dealing with the Stream API:

```
public List<String> validateFlimflam(Flimflam flimflam) {
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    // ... validation code omitted for brevity
    // 'errors' list is populated with any errors; otherwise it returns empty

    return errors;
}
```

I want to stream (Stream API) through a `List<Flimflam>` and populate a `Map<Flimflam,List<String>>` *errors map*, where the key of the map is a `Flimflam` that failed validation, and its corresponding value is the list of validation error strings.

I can achieve this the "old fashioned" way like so:

```
List<Flimflam> flimflams = getSomehow();
Map<Flimflam,List<String>> errorsMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Flimflam ff : flimflams) {
    List<String> errors = validateFlimflam(ff);
    if (!errors.isEmpty() {
        errorsMap.put(ff, errors);
    }
}
```

**How can I accomplish this via the Stream API?**

Comment: Would it make more sense to use a Vavr `Validation`?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Actually, it didn't.  It did not specify where  the `validateFlimflam` method is declared (although one could speculate).  That is important to know exactly how to apply any lambdas or method references.  And strangely enough, the accepted answer doesn't work as it is syntactically incorrect. But I didn't downvote it.

Comment: Then you or someone else could have requested that and given me the opportunity to add more detail. Food for thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
Map<Flimflam,List<String>> errorsMap = flimflams.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f, f-> f::validateFlimflam));
```

`toMap` takes 2 parameters (keyMapper,valueMapper)
In your case key mapper is object from stream itself, and value is calling validateFlimflam on that object

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell where exactly your `validateFlimflam` method is defined.  I suspect it is not in the `Flimflam` class itself since there would be no need to pass an instance of itself to the method. So I presume it is an external method to that class.  Assuming that I would proceed as follows:

thisClass = instance containing `validateFlimflam`. Could be set to `this`

```
Map<Flimflam, List<String>> errorsMap =
        flimflams.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f,
                        thisClass::validateFlimflam));
```

If by chance, `Flimflam` does contain `validateFlimflam` you could do it like this.  Note that this presumes the method takes **no arguments** as they wouldn't be necessary

```
Map<Flimflam, List<String>> errorsMap =
        flimflams.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f,
                        Flimflam::validateFlimflam));
```

Finally, if the containing class is some other class and the `validateFlimflam` method is declared static, then you could do it like this by using the containing class name, **not instance**. Also, in this case, the method would take an argument as defined.

```
Map<Flimflam, List<String>> errorsMap =
        flimflams.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f,
                        SomeClass::validateFlimflam));
```